# Which is more recommendable in kotlin?

Tags: android, variables, kotlin

if i have this button:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/button"      
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
            android:text="@string/button" />
```

which is more advisable in kotlin when it comes to calling views?

this:

```
  val buttonVar: Button = findById(R.id.buuton)
  buttonVar.setOnClickListener{
   //my code
  }
```

or:

```
  button.setOnClickListener{
   //my code
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to performance in `Kotlin` , this is more advisable

```
    button.setOnClickListener{
     //my code
    }
```

Because calling views by their ID directly will generate a local view **cache**.

So the when the view is called the first time kotlin plugin will execute `findViewById` just a single time, and the next time the view gets called, it will get recovered from the cache . So accesing that view will be faster.

You can refer to this link for more informations [enter link description here](https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/)

I hope this will help you, don't forget to accept the answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

First one is recommended now. The reason is because if you do it the second way, you would be using  kotlinx synthetic which is no longer a recommended practice. [Source](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/882241)